# Visual Studio 2010 RC + ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM won't re-target from .NET Framework 4 to 3.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Per the above I am trying to re-target a fresh ASP.NET MVC 2 application in Visual Studio 2010 RTM.

After all sorts of tweaking the closest I am getting is the error below:

> The primary reference "System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

Is there anyone who can assist in having this re-targeted to .NET Framework 3.5 (SP1), or is there perhaps a zip file of a VS 2010 + .NET Framework v3.5 + ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM project already online I could grab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked fine when I upgraded to RTM.

Answer (score 0):

Is this as simple as right clicking the project and then choosing property pages, then choosing build from the menu on the left and then choosing 3.5 from the dropdown?

Comment: Yes, it should be, but re-targeting via that method doesn't work correctly.